# Changes in Shopware5 less-file has no effect

Tags: less, shopware

I've installed [Shopware](https://en-community.shopware.com/Downloads_cat_725.html%20%22shopware%20Download)

1. inherited from the responsive theme and
2. adjusting the colors (less-files).

This worked well with the header and a few other components like `container.less` but not `offcanvas-menu.less`.

In Detail:

### finding the color to change:

For this I first made all colors of the entire shop unique. So I can easily tap the color value over the current shop via a pipette tool.

Then I find the color value in the source code and copy the corresponding less source code components into my new theme. Only then do I change the color.

### copied inside `themes/Frontend`  :

a) `/Responsive/frontend/_public/src/less/_components/offcanvas-menu.less` too

b) `/MyNewTheme/frontend/_public/src/less/_components/offcanvas-menu.less`

the following part :

```
.sidebar--navigation {
    .border-radius();
    background: #0492d6;
    .navigation--entry {
        &:last-child {
            border-bottom: 0 none;
        }
    }
    .navigation--link {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
}
```

and changed **background: #0492d6;** to **background: #003E7e;** inside b)

Complete result: [gist MyNewTheme offcanvas-menu.less](https://gist.github.com/sl5net/f95c14db8c6e52f3ea0405109be2aa39)

But if i reload and grap the color i got again **#0492D6**.

As doppelcheck i changed the color in a) to `background: black;` and its black.

As another doppelcheck i changed the color in `themes/Frontend/MyNewTheme/frontend/_public/src/less/_components/container.less` to background: red; And red is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you also imported it.

Please enter in your themes\Frontend\MyNewTheme\frontend_public\src\less\all.less

@import "_components/offcanvas-menu";